# Dealing with multicollinearity by smoothing coefficients?

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, multicollinearity, splines

I would like to perform a linear regression. However, the predictor variables are families of variables indexed by time. Let's say the regression problem is:

target ~ x(1)+x(2)+...+x(40)+y(1)+...+y(40)

and imagine the x(t) and y(t) are measurements in 40 successive years. The variables inside the families x(t),y(t) are thus highly collinear.

The usual way to deal with this problem would be variable selection. However, in the problem at hand it is much desired that the coefficients the x(t) resp. y(t) variables are chosen smoothly in time, so setting some of them to 0 is not a good choice.

My idea was to choose the coefficients for the variable families as the values of penalised splines with knots every 5 years.

Is there a way to do this in R?
Or is there another way of smoothing the coefficients without the use of splines?

Comment: If it's the case that recent predictor values are more relevant to the response you could consider time series methods for data reduction, e.g. using level & trend from Holt exponential smoothing within each family as predictors. I think this question might benefit from a bit more background.

Comment: Maybe you could model `target ~ x + y` instead and use an ARMA error structure: [Time-Series Regression and Generalized Least Squares](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-timeseries-regression.pdf). What do you intend to do with the model?